# Electron - Set devtools title

Tags: electron

I have an electron app that has multiple devtools windows. All of the devtools windows have the same title 'Devtools', so I want to be able to set the title to something along the lines of 'Devtools (popup)' so it will be easier to differentiate between them.

Creating the devtools browser window with a title property, or setting the title with either
`devtools.title = 'Custom devtools title'` or `window.setTitle('Custom devtools title')`
don't work.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [known bug](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/32545).

One commenter said:

> what worked for me is setting the devtools window title at a delay after creation -

```
let newDevToolsWindow = new BrowserWindow();
window.webContents.setDevToolsWebContents(newDevToolsWindow.webContents);
window.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: "detach" });

setTimeout(() => {
    newDevToolsWindow.setTitle("DevTools Title");
}, 3000);
```

You could try that.